# Terraform to get all subnet id from vpc id

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Currently I have a aws infrastructure that is created manually. I want to import configuration of vpc and subnets. With the

```
terraform import aws_vpc.example vpc-id
```

I can get the cidr block of the vpc. Further with the cidr block I also want to get all the subnet ids as well. Is there a way to get all subnet ids with import command or I have to manually enter every id?

I cannot find any document where all subnet values can be imported? If there is please share

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have vpc_id, then you can use [aws_subnet_ids](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html) data to **automatically** get the ids of its subsets.

Example from docs:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.example.vpc_id
}
```

Comment: How do we then access the individual ID's please?

Comment: @MichaelOlafisoye Using index, e.g. `data.aws_subnet_ids.example[0].id`.